# nginx 502 bad gateway for long running request

Tags: django, nginx

I have a request that takes "a few mins" to process. This works fine when I access it via Django's built in development server.

However when I access it from nginx/uwsgi I get 502 bad gateway.

I have tried increasing the timeout/keepalive settings in nginx.conf but to no effect.

Here is the relevant conf setting:-

```
#keepalive_timeout  0;
client_body_timeout   10;
client_header_timeout 10;
keepalive_timeout     5 5;
send_timeout          10;
```

And nginx debug log errors:-

```
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12654#0: nginx/1.4.2
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12654#0: built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12654#0: OS: Linux 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12654#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:4096
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12655#0: start worker processes
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12655#0: start worker process 12657
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12655#0: start worker process 12658
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12655#0: start worker process 12659
2016/02/03 17:35:33 [notice] 12655#0: start worker process 12660
2016/02/03 17:36:36 [error] 12658#0: *12 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: xxxxxxxx.in, request: "GET /long/url/with?request=params HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://10.176.6.247:8001", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Comment: You shouldn't really do long running tasks online. Offload them onto something life Celery.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You don't even have to use Celery. uWSGI has a built in spooler.
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Spooler.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says `upstream prematurely closed connection`, which means that it's the application server that timed-out. Therefore you need to increase the script execution timeout setting of your application server, i.e.:

```
#uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
harakiri = 200
```

However, after you increase the applictation server timeout, the NGINX proxying timeout might become too low for that, then modify NGIX timeout too, i.e.:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
proxy_read_timeout 200s;
```

or

```
uwsgi_read_timeout 200s;
uwsgi_send_timeout 200s;
```

But in general, as already mentioned in comments, making long running tasks in the same process that parses the request is not recommended with Django.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, the issue is between the Nginx reverse proxy and the back-end server. The parameters you set are timeouts for the clients' request and not for the server's response.

I think (without being sure) that the good parameter in Nginx config is `proxy_read_timeout`: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout